# How to print this output in Java Top students: 33.33%?

Tags: java, math, printing, output, percentage

[image: expected ouput]My output is different ,I got

```
Top students: 30.00%nBetween 4.00 and 4.99: 30.00%nBetween 3.00 and 3.99: 20.00%nFail: 20.00%n Average: 4.06
```

I tried:

```
System.out.printf("Top students: %.2f%%n",p5);
System.out.printf("Between 4.00 and 4.99: %.2f%%n",p4);
System.out.printf("Between 3.00 and 3.99: %.2f%%n",p3);
System.out.printf("Fail: %.2f%%n ",p2);
System.out.printf("Average: %.2f",avg);
```

It should be -every student and given data in every new interval on new line:

```
Top students: 30.00%
Between 4.00 and 4.99: 30.00%
Between 3.00 and 3.99: 20.00%
Fail: 20.00%
Average: 4.06
```

How to fix it?

Comment: It is `\n` not `%n`

Comment: @m0skit0 `%n` works with `printf`.

Comment: I am trying to put one more % between both %% now. It should work.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that the percent characters have special meaning in a String passed to `printf`. Printing a literal percent character requires doubling it: `”%%”`. Because these strings contain `%%n`, the first `%` escapes the second one, resulting in a literal `%`, then the `n` is treated as a literal `n` and included in the output.

To print a literal percent character followed by a newline, you should use `%%%n`.

For example:

```
System.out.printf("Top students: %.2f%%%n",p5);
```